# How can I initialise the GDT?

Tags: x86, kernel, osdev, linker-scripts, gdt

I'm making an operating system and I'm stuck at the GDT. I've tried different tutorials, such as http://www.osdever.net/bkerndev/Docs/gdt.htm and http://www.jamesmolloy.co.uk/tutorial_html/4.-The%20GDT%20and%20IDT.html, but my os crashes always. How can I fix this? I use grub so the kernel is already in protected mode.

boot.asm:

```
section .multiboot
multiboot_start:
dd 0xe85250d6
dd 0
dd multiboot_end - multiboot_start
dd 0x100000000 - (0xe85250d6 + 0 + (multiboot_end - multiboot_start))
dw 0
multiboot_end:
section .text
global gdt_flush
extern gp
gdt_flush:
lgdt [gp]
mov ax, 0x10
mov ds, ax; This line restarts the computer
mov es, ax
mov fs, ax
mov gs, ax
mov ss, ax
jmp 0x08:flush2
flush2:
ret               
extern kernel_main
start:
mov esp, stack_space
call kernel_main
hlt
section .bss
resb 10240
stack_space:
```

kernel.c:

```
#include <tty.h>
#include <log.h>
struct gdt_entry {
unsigned short limit_low;
unsigned short base_low;
unsigned char base_middle;
unsigned char access;
unsigned char granularity;
unsigned char base_high;
} __attribute__((packed));
struct gdt_ptr {
unsigned short limit;
unsigned int base;
} __attribute__((packed));
struct gdt_entry gdt[3];
struct gdt_ptr gp;
extern void gdt_flush();
void gdt_set_gate(int num, unsigned long base, unsigned long limit, unsigned char access, unsigned char gran) {
gdt[num].base_low = (base & 0xFFFF);
gdt[num].base_middle = (base >> 16) & 0xFF;
gdt[num].base_high = (base >> 24) & 0xFF;
gdt[num].limit_low = (limit & 0xFFFF);
gdt[num].granularity = ((limit >> 16) & 0x0F);
gdt[num].granularity |= (gran & 0xF0);
gdt[num].access = access;
}
void gdt_install() {
gp.limit = (sizeof(struct gdt_entry) * 3) - 1;
gp.base = &gdt;
gdt_set_gate(0, 0, 0, 0, 0);
gdt_set_gate(1, 0, 0xFFFFFFFF, 0x9A, 0xCF);
gdt_set_gate(2, 0, 0xFFFFFFFF, 0x92, 0xCF);
gdt_flush();
}
void kernel_main(void){
initterm();
put("Initializing system...\n");
gdt_install();
}
```

linker.ld:

```
SECTIONS
{
. = 1M;
.text BLOCK(4K) : ALIGN(4K)
{
    *(.multiboot)
    *(.text)
}
.data BLOCK(4K) : ALIGN(4K)
{
    *(.data)
}
.bss BLOCK(4K) : ALIGN(4K)
{
    *(COMMON)
    *(.bss)
}
}
```

Makefile:

```
LINKFILES=kernel/boot.o kernel/kernel.o kernel/libk/string/strlen.o kernel/libk/tty/tty.o kernel/libk/ioport/inb.o kernel/libk/ioport/outb.o kernel/libk/serial/serwritechar.o kernel/libk/serial/writetoserial.o kernel/libk    /tty/print.o kernel/libk/log/put.o
compile:
cd kernel && make compile
build:
ld -o devos.bin -Tkernel/linker.ld $(LINKFILES) -melf_i386
mkdir -p iso/boot/grub
mv devos.bin iso/boot/devos.bin
cp grub.cfg iso/boot/grub/grub.cfg
grub-mkrescue -o devos.iso iso
.SILENT:
all: compile build
```

kernel makefile:

```
compile:
cd libk && make compile
nasm -felf32 boot.asm
gcc -c kernel.c -I libk -std=gnu99 -m32 -ffreestanding
```

Comment: You'll have to post your code and show us your attempt that fails that you expect to work.

Comment: Have you tried single-stepping it in BOCHS's built-in debugger, or some other way of debugging?

Comment: Yes, I have used hlt instructions and the problem is in the `mov ds, ax` line

Comment: Are you building this as 64-bit code by mistake? Can you show us the commands you use to assemble, compile, and link the code?

Comment: No, I'm compiling against i386 and I added the makefile to my question. @MichaelPetch

Comment: i'm assuming you haven't turned on interrupts (with STI) since your code hasn't set up an IDT (interrupt descriptor table).

Comment: This sort of puzzles me with one exception. One possibility is that your code isn't executing as you expected. What I did just now notice is that you have no `global start` directive in your `boot.asm` file. The linker will by default attempt to find a global symbol `start` if you don't specify an `ENTRY` directive in your linker script. If there is no global `start` then the linker uses the entry point to the first VMA address which ix 0x100000 in your case. That's not what you want. That might be causing you serious issues. Try adding `global start` to your `boot.asm` and see what happens.

Comment: By itself I do not see an issue with this code (except possibly for warnings about type casting). I suspect that either there is a build/link related issue or `initterm` turns on interrupts at some point. Interrupts will cause a triple fault. But I'm betting more towards your code not specifying a global `start` symbol and the entry point into your kernel is not actually at the `start` label as a result - which would create undefined behaviour (triple fault likely).

Comment: Adding `global start` worked, thanks a lot @MichaelPetch!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code appears to be okay assuming that `initterm` which you don't show us doesn't have a bug or turns on interrupts with the *STI* instructions. Unhandled interrupts or no proper Interrupt Descriptor Table (IDT) will cause a triple fault.

I suspect though the issue may not be the above at all. Generally speaking if you are creating *ELF* objects that intend to be loaded by a Multiboot(2) compatible bootloader you should be explicitly setting the entry point in your linker script. Setting it tells the linker explicitly where you want the bootloader to start executing your code. In your case you have a `start` label in your code so I think you intended that to be the entry point.

At the top of your linker script add:

```
ENTRY(start)
```

The linker expects that the symbol `start` will be a global label. In your assembler file with the multiboot2 header make sure `start` is global with this line:

```
global start
```

This should be enough to properly set the entry point. If you explicitly place an `ENTRY` directive in your linker script the linker will warn you if it can't find the global label you define as the entry point and will tell you the default entry point address. The default is usually the starting Virtual Memory Address (VMA) in the *ELF* object. In your case that would be 0x100000.

You will not get any warning if the `ENTRY` directive is not present. In that case the linker usually quietly searches for a **global** label called `start` and if it doesn't find one sets the entry point to the starting VMA of the *ELF* object. Specifying a starting address with `ENTRY` directive in the linker script will tell you if there is a problem and what VMA it used as an entry point if it is missing.

General rule of thumb: Always specify an entry point in the linker script with the `ENTRY` directive and globally export that label in your code.